# Bootstrap 3: Hide main navbar on Desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is fairly simple but I got stuck trying to hide the Bootstrap main navbar on screens greater than 768px.

I don't want to hide the `<nav>` tag. I just want to hide the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default custom-menu" id="navbar-collapse-1">...</div>`

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/denuee0t/4/)**

```
<nav class="navbar-blue" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- User menu to show on screens < 768px -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default custom-menu" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav client-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: But I don't want to disable Bootstrap's responsive features. I just want to hide the div with the menu items on Desktop.

Comment: If you use the media query in your fiddle and target the "navbar-blue" class it goes away on screens greater than 768 and then appears in the condensed toggleable form on smaller screens, you almost had it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things affecting your ability to control this style

1. The style that sets the `display:block` for the navbar uses `!important`.  You need to override that with your own `!important` rule
2. The style you are using has lower specificity than the one that is making it `display:block`.  The style in effect is `.navbar-collapse.collapse` (two classes specified), whereas yours is simply `.custom-menu` (only one class).

To remedy both of these you need a rule similar to this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
   .navbar-collapse.custom-menu {
        display: none!important;
    }
}
```

That will cause the menu to be hidden at those sizes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4jgL2hfy/

Comment: Hey mate you are saving my life again. Thank you so much!

Comment: @brunodd lol. You're welcome. Always glad to help where I can. :)